# How to set column width of excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, excellibrary

I am using ExcelLibrary for creating excel sheet. I need to increase width of some columns. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
var ObjWorkBook = new Workbook();
var ObjWorkSheet = new Worksheet(ObjDataTable.TableName);
ObjWorksheet.Cells[0, 0] = new Cell("FirstName");
ObjWorksheet.Cells[0, 1] = new Cell("Email");
//var Width = ObjWorksheet.Cells.ColumnWidth.Default + 200;
ObjWorkBook.Worksheets.Add(ObjWorkSheet);
```

Comment: ObjWorksheet.Columns[1].ColumnWidth = 50;

Comment: I guess you are talking about some other dll. But, I am using ExcelLibrary.SpreadSheet for creating spread sheet. Worksheet class is not having a property named "Columns".

Comment: Check if this works for you: ObjWorksheet.Cells.ColumnWidth[0, 1] = 100;

Comment: yes, It worked out... just a little modification... as I want to change width of entire column not a single cell... so
ObjWorksheet.Cells.ColumnWidth[0] = 15000;

Answer (score 1):

To change the width of a column, [use `Range.ColumnWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837430%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

For example:

```
// Increase column A by 200
ObjWorksheet.Columns["A"].ColumnWidth += 200

// Alternately.
OjbWorksheet.Columns[1].ColumnWidth += 200
```

Of course you can put this in a loop to edit multiple columns.

```
// Increase columns A-E by 200.
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i += 1)
{
    OjbWorksheet.Columns[i].ColumnWidth += 200
}
```